# My serializers depend on each other, how can I ensure both are used

Tags: java, serialization, gson

Imagine I have two classes, `MyClass` and `MyOtherClass`. I've written a serializer for `MyClass`. Without it, trying to serialize `MyOtherClass` won't work (because `MyClass` isn't serializable without the serializer I've written).

```
package com.mycompany.javatest;

import com.google.gson.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class JavaTest {

    static class MyClass {

        private int someValue = 123;
    }

    static class MyOtherClass {

        private MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    }

    static class MyClassSerializer implements JsonSerializer<MyClass> {

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(MyClass t, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc) {

            JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
            // (Doing some magic to serialize the object here...)
            result.add("someValue", jsc.serialize(t.someValue));
            return result;

        }
    }

    static class MyOtherClassSerializer implements JsonSerializer<MyOtherClass> {

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(MyOtherClass t, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc) {

            JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
            result.add("mc", jsc.serialize(t.mc)); // <--- Will fail if not using the MyClassSerializer
            return result;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
        gb.registerTypeAdapter(MyOtherClassSerializer.class, new MyOtherClassSerializer());
        Gson gson = gb.create();
        MyOtherClass object = new MyOtherClass();

        String json = gson.toJson(object, MyOtherClass.class); // <--- MyClassSerializer.serialize MUST be invoked, or this will fail

    }
}
```

My question is, how can I enforce that `MyClassSerializer` is registered when `MyOtherClassSerializer` is registered? The obvious answer is to just register **both** type adapters, but I'd like to know if there is a way to enforce registering both when registering `MyOtherClassSerializer`. One option is to only allow the type adapters to be accessed by a "register" method like this, but I don't like this solution. I still want the `MyClassSerializer` to be accessible.

```
public void registerMyOtherClassSerializer(GsonBuilder builder) {

    builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new MyClassSerializer());
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyOtherClass.class, new MyOtherClassSerializer());

}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Instead of providing two separate `ClassSerializer`s, you could provide a single `TypeAdapterFactory` (https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) for your custom classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Kläger. This is what I ended up doing:

```
package com.mycompany.javatest;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.*;
import com.google.gson.stream.*;
import java.io.*;

public class JavaTest {

    static class MyClass {
        private final int someValue = 123;
    }

    static class MyOtherClass {
        private final MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
        gb.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new MyTypeAdapterFactory());
        Gson gson = gb.create();
        MyOtherClass object = new MyOtherClass();

        String json = gson.toJson(object, MyOtherClass.class);
        System.out.println(json);

    }

    static class MyTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

        @Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> tt) {

            if (MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(tt.getRawType())) {
                return (TypeAdapter<T>) new MyClassAdapter();
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static class MyClassAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyClass> {

            @Override
            public MyClass read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter writer, MyClass t) throws IOException {
                writer.beginObject();
                writer.name("someValue");
                writer.value(t.someValue); // (Doing some magic to serialize the object here...)
                writer.endObject();
            }
        }
    }
}
```